# How do you get your account suspended

Tags: discussion, support

[rich-b](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5640/rich-b) has a message at the top of his profile that his account is suspended  and that there is 22 hours left. I tried to click on the link [temporarily suspended](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) that points to blog question, but the page will not open for me for some reason.

What is the deal behind getting your account suspended?

Comment: Ah, you know his name is viewable in the revisions, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the Penalty box blog post

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Edit:

The main rule about the penalty box is "Don't be a jerk" some examples of being a jerk are:

- Other users react negatively to your posts, posting negative responses and generally causing a commotion.
- There is a broad sense of community resentment over your behavior, and you are frequently cited in discussion about the community.
- The moderators get regular email complaints about your behavior.
- You make snide or rude comments “behind people’s backs”, in public places.

The consequences are:

- Your account will be locked at 1 reputation.
- Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how long.
- You will be unable to ask or answer questions.

Comment: I make the point in my question that for some reason that page will not open up for me.

Comment: As noted by the OP and confirmed by http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/, that page is down right now.

Comment: Did you even read the question?

Comment: I apologize, I didn't realize that the link on the account suspended went to the penalty box blog post. I have revised the answer and included a link to the cached version of the page, if that doesn't work for you I can include some further information

Comment: The blog must have gone down in the last 10 minutes or so. I was just reading this particular blog post in the last 15 minutes.

Comment: To bad they didn't publish a little blurb that pointed to the answers/questions/comments of the posts that were offensive!

Comment: I think the question in question has been deleted, but I sincerely doubt that a single or even several posts pushed him into the box, the user has a legacy of... impishness... as well as a flair for sarcasm & strong opinions

Comment: "You make snide or rude comments 'behind people’s backs', in public places." ... "you are frequently cited in discussion about the community."...so don't say anything bad about someone, unless they are bad, in which case you need to frequently cite them behind their backs which now makes you the bad person...j/k but it does pretty much illustrate that the rule is "its a popularity contest".

Answer (score 3):

#### From [*A Day in the Penalty Box*](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/):

> If a moderator has warned you several
> times via email about behavior, and
> that behavior continues, for a period
> of 2 to 7 days, your account will be
> in timed suspension.
>
> - Your account will be locked at 1 reputation.
> - Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how long.
> - You will be unable to ask or answer questions.
>
> At the end of this period, your
> reputation will be recalculated, and
> your account will resume as normal. As
> I said, we don’t hold grudges; the
> point of all this is to address the
> behavior. If the behavior improves,
> we’re cool.