# Users in penalty box are still able to post comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, account-suspension

I believe this is a bug. There are at least two users in the "penalty box" who are able to continue posting comments. See this thread: [How do you get your account suspended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18270/how-do-you-get-your-account-suspended) with comments from Rich B and Welbog.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Considering the two users in question were put in the box for comments in the first place, this should definitely be corrected.

Answer (score 5):

Suspended accounts are dropped to a rep-value of 1, which is the required reputation to post comments according to the MetaSO-FAQ.

As suggested by others, if you are suspended for abusing comments, perhaps you should be suspended from posting additional comments as well. "By-design bug" maybe?

Comment: Good catch. IIRC, SO requires 50 or so rep to post comments. They probably didn't bother blocking the comment feature since the rep drop would take care of that.

Comment: @Jon Yeah, I was thinking of reputation in context of SO, which confused me initially. Had to check here.

Comment: The penalty box rep ought to be 0 on meta in that case.

Comment: @tvanfosson True. Probably an oversight when implementing Meta.

Answer (score 2):

The Penalty Box blog post mentions only restricting the posting of questions and answers, so perhaps is by design.

> If a moderator has warned you several
>   times via email about behavior, and
>   that behavior continues, for a period
>   of 2 to 7 days, your account will be
>   in timed suspension.
>
> Your account will be locked at 1
>   reputation.
>   Your user page will have a
>   visual indication that you are in
>   timed suspension, and for how long.
>   You will be unable to ask or answer
>   questions.

Comment: Ahh. Perhaps this is more of a feature request, then. It seems like account-suspension should extend to comments as well (especially when it's comments that lead to the suspension!)

Comment: @Jon B: That could be interpreted as having different suspension modes, depending on the behaviour that gets someone put in the box. I would disagree with that, only one suspension mode is needed. But you're right, that should include comments.