# Can we implement temporary automatic comment ban on 'x' number of validated rude comment flags?

Tags: feature-request, comments, new-users, comment-flags, be-nice-policy

There's been problems with abusive comments since the site started. [What's with all the rude comments recently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/whats-with-all-the-rude-comments-recently)

We still haven't managed to conquer the issue. [Negative comments drive new users away, how can we fix this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172970/negative-comments-drive-new-users-away-how-can-we-fix-this)

Users can be issued chat bans and post bans. The API automatically bans IP addresses with validated spam flags. (*Would it be difficult to implement comment bans? Would mods have the power to impose comment restrictions?*).

Although comments have been classically referred to as second class citizens, rude comments on the site are the one place that is driving people away.

**Can we implement temporary automatic comment ban on 'x' number of validated rude comment flags?**
*It would probably be better if the exact heuristics were not disclosed publicly, much like the serial voting scripts*

This question [Can we have a "Sorry, we are no longer accepting comments from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92158/can-we-have-a-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-comments-from-this-account) was asked 7 years ago. Can we revisit it?

This question is related, but is asking for a more complex approach:
[Implement a Selective Comment Ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233916/implement-a-selective-comment-ban)

Comment: Strongly related: [Can the recidivism system be applied to comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254743/178816)

Comment: @TravisJ I hope this bounty helps to push the community team to implement this asap.

Comment: Related: [Comment flags are deemed helpful if the parent post is deleted...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280413/273494)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This suggestion is coming up with increasing frequency in various forms; one of my colleagues expressed amazement this morning that we don't already do this - he'd spent the morning cleaning up after an abusive comment-author, only to find this person had kept right on leaving abusive comments the whole while.

Journeyman and Catija have suggested a couple of ways in which this *might* be problematic, but in truth we need not speculate: such an automatic-ban system *already exists* in Chat!

...this system is [not exactly well-loved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203346/flags-in-chat-are-defective-by-design). While I don't think it's as bad as folks make it out to be, it's hard to ignore the fact that it often has the opposite effect from what is desired: abuse-banned folks often come back angrier and more abusive than when they left.

Of course, comments aren't *supposed to be* chat. But that raises an important question...

### Why aren't we rate-limiting comments based on how they're used?

If the intent of comments isn't to chat up other users all day long, then why does the system allow them to be used this way?

- Some users are in the habit of leaving dozens, even hundreds of comments on dozens or even hundreds of posts... Every day.
- Some users are in the habit of conducting long, detailed back and forth conversations in comments under their posts.
- Some users regularly leave multiple comments back-to-back under the same post.
- Some users do all of the above even when 50-75% or more of their comments are deleted on a regular basis.

...and the system does very little to discourage any of this. There's a tiny bit of rate-limiting in terms of how fast you can post comments, but nothing stopping you from posting *just a bit slower* than that all day long, every day, on as many posts as you wish to.

For a moderator, the only options for handling persistent comment abuse are:

1. Suspend the user from the site
2. Do nothing.
3. Laugh madly while the world burns (functionally equivalent to #2)

So from a user's perspective, they get absolutely no pushback at all until suddenly all of their privileges are gone... And on larger sites where comments can readily go unnoticed, this may take months or even years.

In essence, the system and UI facilitate - even encourage - abuse, even while flaggers and moderators are expected to stop it.

### Proposed rate-limits

Instead of automatic bans, I'd suggest something like this:

1. Limit everyone to some number of comments per day *and* some smaller number of posts on which they can leave comments. Let's say... 100 comments / day and 50 commented posts / day by default.
2. Reduce both of these limits severely if the % of deleted comments for a given user exceeds some nominal threshold over the past week. For the sake of discussion, let's say anything over 20% gets you knocked back to 20/10, and anything over 50% puts you at 2/1. Yeah. If more'n half of your comments get deleted, you only get to post two comments on at most one post per day.
3. For the purpose of these tests, ignore auto-generated comments (duplicates, canned off-topic reasons, review deletion comments) - those are *supposed to be* deleted in many cases.
4. Show the number of remaining comments below the comment form whenever a user starts to compose a comment.

My prediction is that this system would dramatically reduce the number of noisy, snarky, rude comments *even for people who never hit the limit*, simply by making it obvious that they're using up a limited resource.

But for those determined to push forward, it would add real *teeth* to flaggers' and moderators' cleanup efforts by drastically reducing authors' ability to generate huge numbers of worthless comments.

Comment: 100/50 seems like quite a low number. This is far below the top _undeleted_ amount of 564/348 and there have been 4,214 times where the number of undeleted comments would have broken this limit. Is there any particular reason why this limit?

Comment: I love that you address the current all or nothing approach to rude commenters and it's usually nothing as the account suspension is so severe. Rate limiting sounds great. At the end of the day if two sides wage a comment war and flag each other - they will soon learn to make one or two choice comments and then to walk away. Of course there will be the flood of meta complaints, but the community will soon tire of duplicated complaints of "why was I comment rate limited.. " or [maybe not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=flag+declined+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: It'd be worth considering that if a user removes their own comment (a behavior we want to see), this should not count against them on the path to rate limiting and, (assuming the comment were posted that day) might actually give them back an additional comment to use. Neither of these would be done if the comments were removed by moderators or the other users.

Comment: Yeah, that's worth a look @Catija; also, I'd want to simulate this with past data to establish less arbitrary thresholds should we ever decide to implement it.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards 100/50 seems low for a day? I think it will probably depend greatly on the site. And, perhaps, it can be like flagging privileges... users who show they know how to use comments well, can be given more/day to use. Those who fail, lose them. I have many users on IPS who only have ~300 comments *total* but close to half of their comments are deleted, so 100 in a day would be quite more than needed for us.

Comment: 100/50 **per day** is incredibly rare, @ben.

Comment: IPS has users with over 80% of their comments deleted in recent days, @Catija. IPS is becoming the "pathological example" in comment discussions.

Comment: This is probably not a good time to say "yay"?

Comment: "Some users do all of the above even when 50-75% or more of their comments are deleted on a regular basis."  You aren't actually told when your comments are deleted, are you?  So people probably just never look back and never realize...

Comment: @SouthpawHare Oh, sure... *some* don't... And some spend large amounts of time on Meta complaining about it. Either way, though... they should be aware that the comments are problematic. I am somewhat concerned about users who actually do post helpful comments that are deleted *because* the post has been edited. These are definitely in the minority but I'd want to be certain that these very helpful users weren't penalized in the same bucket as users who are actually abusing comments.

Comment: @Catija I was thinking more about people who don't notice and don't complain, who never look back at anything they write, and don't notice their comments getting deleted behind them.  In that case, it's not really their fault, right?  They're getting no feedback.

Comment: Presumably, this is their feedback, @SouthpawHare . If they see a countdown on their number of remaining comments/day, they'll realize that something's going on. When implemented, it'd hopefully be accompanied by a � that would let them know that comments are now limited to x per day and include a link to the comment policy on the network. If they choose to ignore that, the first penalty step down should explain why they're further limited and how to recover from that, again with a link to the comment policy. The tiers allow them to continue to comment after being made aware there's a problem.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35501/please-return-the-comment-rate-limit-to-a-flat-30-seconds

Comment: Two very major things missing here: what about **self deleted** comments? And as other comment mentioned, if such thing takes place, we ***must*** let users see their own deleted comments, same way we can see our deleted posts, so we can know what we did wrong. Sometimes comments we posted years ago are flagged and deleted, we *can't* be expected to remember what we wrote back then.

Comment: Third thing which is less vital, I don't think comments deleted as "no longer needed" should cause same "punishment" as rude/abusive comments, if at all. (And yes, I know lots of my own comments are being deleted as such, and prefer to not get myself comment rate limited)

Comment: @Catija "hopefully be accompanied by a � that would let them know that comments are now limited" - what is the "�"? For me it appears as question mark inside black rhombus.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's what it is. It's a symbol regularly used on websites for helper text. Hovering over it would open a popup box (or clicking would take you to a related help page). The idea being, if someone was curious what the countdown was, we'd put it right there for them to see.

Comment: I like this in combination with autoflags or similar if possible, so that if there are users who are consistently bumping up against limits mods can have the opportunity to notice and take further action. If it's worth limiting folks to only 1 or 2 comments a day for very long, it might well be worth just suspending them.

Comment: I think you're probably overestimating both how much you comment *and* how many of those comments are deleted (for any reason), @ShadowWizard. That said, I think allowing for self-deleted comments is reasonable for the simple reason that it encourages a useful behavior.

Comment: This would, I believe, add some complexity to the comments table, as we now should know whenever a comment is canned (ie. added by the system) or not. Is SE willing to invest resources into it?

Comment: wonder how hard would it be to make comments limits configurable per site because it doesn't look like one size fits all. Say, 100/50 limit feels a bit... tight for prolific answerers at Stack Overflow and on the other hand, might be too high at smaller sites that are impacted by [comments problem](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2748/168)

Comment: could also just apply the limits to comments on 3rd-party posts, @gnat

Comment: you mean, comments on own posts could be excluded from limits? that would make a pretty good sense. This way, even uniform network wide limit could probably be OK

Comment: yeah... I think it's probably worth considering comments that everyone can make (own post, answers to own post, automatic dup-comments, etc) and comments that only privileged users can make as two mostly-different categories, with vastly different motivations and abuse scenarios.

Comment: @Shog9 never said to allow self deletion, my point is about users who post snarky comments so post author see them, then after few minutes they delete the comments to hide their tracks. How to address this?

Comment: Arguably an entirely different (and uncommon) form of abuse there, @Shadow. Not that they should be given a pass, but... That sort of strategy takes this from "unintentionally disruptive" to "intentionally abusive" territory. Might be worth implementing a trigger of some sort to detect it separate from what is being discussed here.

Comment: What @ShadowWizard is talking about was actually [one of the first things I came to MSE to look for a solution to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256948/retain-viewable-record-of-directed-deleted-comments)... and I was pretty much told that the comment being gone was all that mattered, not my being abused.

Comment: @Catija that's really sad to hear, since this kind of abuse is the worst.

Comment: I've run into that too, @Catija; it's annoying, but arguably a deficiency in the app. Regardless, I don't think we're gonna fix it via rate limits without massive collateral damage.

Comment: I was a bit concerned about the suggested 100/50 limit but unless [this query is incorrect](https://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/844563/comments-per-day) I'm *way* below that. But why even add a standard limit that most people won't ever hit if the point is to only meaningfully limit in two situations where the original limit is rather unrelated?

Comment: Numbers above are fairly arbitrary, @Lilienthal (should be in the right ballpark, but based on a spot-check not detailed analysis). That said, a great many limits here are set higher than the vast, vast majority of users will ever hit: the primary purpose is to stop unusual forms of abuse, not cause daily hardship. There is a potential secondary benefit however... Simply setting a visible limit on something can change how folks perceive it. Right now, comments are often seen as essentially free - but this hides the cost to others of gobs of comments clogging up a question or answer.

Comment: Hopefully if your comments get deleted, there is some form of notification. The penalty in the rate-limit is also hopefully finer-grained than two thresholds, both to be give more feedback to the user, and to give _teeth_ to flaggers and moderators instead of a _guillotine_.

Comment: Yes! I want this. I like all of it.

Comment: @shog9 an ETA would be cool :) me too I want that. I asked for moderation protocol for comment in other discussion, but I think this proposal will maybe remove the other need, but, most of all, it will help moderator to have more time to moderate.

Comment: How would the reductions for deleted comments account for obsolete comments?  We want people to ask clarifying questions, and we want those comments to get deleted when the post gets edited, and we can no longer tell the difference between obsolete and just noise (they're both "no longer needed").

Comment: If you're cleaning up your own comments, they probably shouldn't count @Monica. If someone else has to clean them up, they probably should.

Comment: @Shog9 consider the case where somebody leaves a question in a comment and the author answers in an edit and flags the now-obsolete comment.  Or the author answers in a comment and a third party edits the post and flags both comments.  (I see that a fair bit.)  Unless pinged, the person who left the comment might never see the update and thus know to delete his own comment.  I don't want to penalize people who are trying to be helpful in this way, nor do I think we should expect people to monitor their "could you edit to address X?" comments for followup.

Comment: So you don't think folks should monitor their own comments, but you expect other people to monitor them, flag them, and delete them, @Monica? And you expect this to be done for... Lessee... In the ballpark of 20 comments per day per person?

Comment: Monitoring a request for clarification is expensive compared to a flag from the person who fixed the problem. Most of the time (on main, not meta) when I ask an author to clarify something it's not because I personally care; it's because there's a problem in the post and fixing it will make the site better. We see complaints all the time about commentless actions; there's even a "closed without comment" flag on beta sites. I think there is a class of (singleton) comment that results from *generosity* on the part of the commenter and we should try to account for it. Hard w/o "obsolete" though.

Comment: That's not what I'm getting at, @Monica. For this to be an issue, to even warrant that kind of extra work, it would necessarily involve a LOT of comments. Almost no one posts dozens of comments every day. Those that do tend to break into a couple of very distinct categories: extremely helpful people, and extremely... unhelpful... people... I don't care if the person who posts 12 helpful comments a day can't post 100 helpful comments. I do care that the person who posts 100 helpful comments can post 100 helpful comments... And I care that the person who posts 100 rude comments cannot.

Comment: Oh, I think I see -- you're saying that this category of comments is such a small proportion of the total that they'd disappear into the noise?  Ok, I can see that.

Comment: Essentially, yes. It would take a very... specific... approach to both create enough temporary comments for this to be a problem *and* be attentive enough to not be causing a bigger problem already ***and*** also be inattentive enough to not notice. I still have to run a proper simulation here, but... Frankly, we're not even close to being thorough enough at cleaning up comments for flag reasons to even matter here outside of cases where someone posts *nothing* but abusive comments.

Comment: [Laugh madly while the world burns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuoKNZjr8_U) **:D** Did you know you're the first mod *and the first user ever* who received a [sportsmanship badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/119?page=2) on meta.se?  I'll have to review my opinion of you... **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: I did, @Fabby. It's an important badge and an important behavior; I think we should all try to earn it.

Comment: One of my primary goals in life is to make people around me happier than they were before they met me.  (I'm halfway there on the sportsmanship badge, but apparently upvoting first and answering next doesn't seem to count towards the score or I would've gotten it a long time ago...)  **>:-)**

Comment: So... when mods suddenly get decently good at handling "obsolete" flags, well-meaning folks whose requests for clarification go heard are no longer able to post these comments in the required amount? I've seen no advice so far telling people to pay attention to the clarification requests they're making - and race the moderators to delete them faster once they're done with their job. You really shouldn't be punishing people for having their comments deleted when deleting useful comments as soon as the recipient reads them. is the recommended course of action for moderators...

Comment: This would make far more sense if we were only talking about comments deleted as R/A as counting towards the comment ban...

Comment: Among the comments we're now supposed to self-delete are those countless comments that the system helpfully posts for us when we recommend deletion from the review queues. What happens if I want to recommend deletion but I can't comment because my previous recommendation lead to the answer being improved? Will this next guy not be so lucky to know why they're having their answer deleted? The system would then be severely discouraging improvement of content...

Comment: @JohnDvorak - Where did you get the idea that mods delete comments as soon as the recipient reads them?

Comment: @TravisJ Correction: as soon as the recepient reads them and the comment thread is flagged. I've seen it happen discussed on meta. Can't find the relevant post, sorry.

Comment: Again, I think the solution here is to not count self-deleted comments, @John. If you're making more work for someone else, there should be limits to how much work you can generate.

Comment: I take it's better to just delete someone's answer and not tell them how to fix it, then, because then there's nothing that moderators have to do afterwards? I also suppose that the official advice on how to clean up old threads will now change to "delete your half, then ping the other side" (again, to reduce moderator workload)?

Comment: That's been common practice for years, @John. Over twice as many comments are deleted by their own authors than by anyone else - mods, flags, automated scripts - put together. Folks tend to comment when they take an interest in a post - and that interest doesn't necessarily evaporate once they've left the comment. The exceptional cases where commenters get into long, argumentative discussions or leave scores of snarky, unhelpful comments on posts they have no interest in improving... Are just that: exceptional. And right now, we make it easier to be exceptionally unhelpful than to be helpful.

Comment: I really dislike back-to-back comments that are obviously unnecessary. **IF** it's a helpful and constructive comment that runs out of space and requires a second comment that's  OK. What really spots a 'problem back-to-back comment' is that each is short and a minute apart. It's like they're saying: "I read a few words and felt like I need to chime-in", "I read a bit more, here's a point I disagree with", "I don't understand this part, explain yourself!", "My answer would be better than yours but instead of sharing it with everyone I'll just express how wrong you are; without explaining why".

Answer (score 14):

This doesn't sit well with me for reasons I outline in a [similar post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365854/4548692).

> That said, I strongly reject the idea of an automated warning being sent to a user for this. If the likelihood of a comment being incorrectly validated as rude/abusive was low - or if there were a way to change the flag validation after the fact, it'd be one thing but the default moderator UI - particularly when viewing comments on posts - makes it very easy to accidentally validate a rude/abusive comment flag just by deleting the comment - if they're viewing the post directly, the moderator may not know the comment was flagged at all!

This is about a *warning* and that's not even nearly as problematic as an actual ban. The automatic ban, as I see it, has several problems:

1. It's really easy for moderators to inadvertently validate a rude or abusive comment flag on a comment that they don't think is rude or abusive and there's no way to rectify the situation after the flag is handled.
   Without any sort of improvement to the moderator UI to emphasize the fact that a comment is flagged as rude or abusive, the chance for error is very high. This is particularly problematic on comments that have both rude or abusive flags and no longer needed flags. You'd have to decline all of the flags, since you can't pick which flags to decline on comments.
2. Three users can validate rude or abusive flags on comments if the comment has no upvotes.
   I'm not a huge fan of using "users could abuse it" as a reason to not do something in general but (right now) we have zero information as moderators that comments were deleted by the community unless we happen to be reviewing deleted comments on a post and notice it and, in the case of rude or abusive comment flags, we get an automatic flag letting us know that three comments were deleted as rude or abusive in seven days.
   At the very least, such an implementation would require this to trigger the auto flag first and consider whether the moderators have acted on it or not (with a mod message or suspension)...

And at this point, I have to wonder... **why should this be automatic if it's easily *accidentally* triggered and we're already telling the moderators "hey, this may be a problem, you should look at it"**... just let the moderators take away the comment everywhere privilege themselves for X days instead of a full suspension...

3. It shouldn't be a comment ban... it should be removal of the [Comment Everywhere privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).
   This may sound like splitting hairs but if we're not taking away their ability to post, they need to be able to comment on their own posts or on answers to their questions. If they can't even be civil there, they should be getting a suspension, not a comment timeout.

Plus, if they're going to make it possible to remove the comment everywhere privilege... it should be something that a moderator can do and it should be possible to see all rude or abusive flagged comments in one page. Right now, you can see all flagged comments but can not sort by flag type.

I'd much rather have a comment suspension that requires moderators to explain to a user why they've lost the comment everywhere privilege along with removing it. This should include a link to the user's flagged and deleted comments since the users can't generally see their deleted comments. This allows moderators to prevent comments from both users who are consistently rude in comments (other than outright suspending them) **and** users who are just constantly using comments inappropriately, which is a problem I have on one of the sites I moderate.

If this were to be implemented, a lot of other changes would need to be made to reduce the accidental triggering and allow moderators to undo the ban if it were triggered accidentally.

Comment: ... that said, the answer from Tim Post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300571/please-give-the-moderators-option-to-revoke-the-privilege-for-commenting) seems to imply that they'd rather have an automatic ban than a manual one... but I don't really understand the reasoning there.

Comment: Honestly, this reads like a post more concerned with moderator error, than addressing the issue. Mods can make errors on anything and to persistently  validate rude flags incorrectly to a point to trip such a bam would mean there's a problem with that moderator's ability at that point in time. A comment suspension is different to the comment everywhere privilege. There's no reason to allow the person to comment under their own posts if they don't know how to behave under any post. Currently the community is not gathering and abusing the comment flag system,.../

Comment: ...  as with all else, abuse of the system needs to be addressed. As it stands a certain number of rude flags will automatically raise a mod flag, if the flags are being incorrectly validated a mod has an opportunity to review this. There doesn't need to be a custom mod message for every ban, there isn't one for chat.

Comment: It seems like y'all don't actually disagree *that* much; if the UI were cleared up and there were enough transparency and the thresholds were high enough to avoid accidents, the concerns here would be addressed? It's not that the fundamental idea of automatic bans is bad?

Comment: If a moderator can *accidentally* validate enough RUDABUS flags to trigger a threshold, that's a problem with the moderation system or the individual usage. We're not talking three-and-out, but surely something more like "greater than X per month or greater than Y in the last Z months, whichever is the lower limit" with XYZ all being chosen to avoid this exact problem.

Comment: @Nij Yes, it's a problem with the UI/system. It still means significant false positives. The common scenario is, people argue, both sides get flagged by the other side as some mix of rude and no longer need, mods clean up the whole thing, flags get validated. So the signal to noise ratio could be really really bad here, with really active users not necessarily looking significantly better than the problem users. Again doesn't mean the fundamental idea is bad, just something to address beforehand.

Answer (score 9):

I'm against it being *purely* automatic but I think a good many of the reasons Yvette has brought up is valid. I'd rather this work like a regular suspension (with mods involved) than a 'silent' question or answer ban since in many cases human intervention might be needed. In a sense, comments are *very* much a *people* problem.

> Although comments have been classically referred to as second class citizens, rude comments on the site are the one place that is driving people away.

This is kind of true. Between the fact that the only option we have is to mod message and/or suspend and that there's no real downside *until* some moderator goes "Man, this guy has gone too far", I think we're failing here. Policing comments is also pretty darned hard, especially since there's so many of them. Especially where users change their names often, and with the lack of easy visibility of deleted posts, I for one can't keep track of them all. An automatic comment suspension would probably take care of many of them, but I suspect what I'd really want to see are broader trends.

> Can we implement temporary automatic comment ban on 'x' number of validated rude comment flags?

Well, this can be an effect. That said, being automatic temporarily puts off the problem, not solves it. I'm not too sure a constantly argumentative user will stop commenting in such a manner. *If* automatic - suspensions likely need to be along a sliding scale of time.

Also, sometimes you might want to get someone to stop digging themselves into a hole too quickly and if its automatic, clearly the hole is large enough.

If a user is *consistently* getting RA flags warranted or otherwise, there's probably issues with interactions between people. A comment ban for R/A comments *should* also have some mechanism to inform mods for follow up.

Much like chat suspensions though, an additional option should be the option to *remove* the chat ban if a more personal approach is felt to work.

And well, some folks just need to stop commenting, and if slapping them with a suspension helps, that's great.

I'd also add that, well *its not just new users*. There's a few users who've been around my site a while, who get in trouble in comments. They're too easily baited and being 'encouraged' to step out of an argument would be nice.

So, I like the general idea. I just see that its part of a broader solution.

Comment: As with any bad behaviour - the automatic suspensions could be annotated into the user's history, if the person keeps offending, then account suspensions can be implemented. Currently there's next to no consequences for rude comments - unless it's a blown up fight - which has allowed users to be rude over and over under other people's posts without pause. A comment suspension provides a pause. AS to whether people learn from suspensions, that's up to each individual and we don't have a lot of control over that.

Comment: er ^ pretty much those things - other than that "We don't have a lot of control over that". I'm an optimist and I figure we can at least win a few over ;p

Comment: Annotations aren't necessarily seen. To get mods to validate, whether it's "this was unjustified" or "this should've been more severe", we need autoflags or similar. And if we're going to validate anyway, seems nice to validate *before* the ban. I think we all agree there should be more consequences for rude comments, no one is questioning that. This is just about exactly what consequences to implement and how.