# Why did my question get closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This is the question in question: [Free shipping in satchmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651457/free-shipping-in-satchmo).

Why has it been closed? It IS programming (or at the very least library-usage) related.

Comment: You are right. It's not off topic. It's maybe just a very vague question.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe "off topic" is wrong, but you did not show any effort of trying to do it yourself so people probably thought you're asking to get it on silver plate.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187600/cant-set-the-shop-language-in-satchmo) for example, as you see the person there posted code and lots of details, most probably that's what is missing in your post.

Comment: Well, I understand what a 'good' and a 'bad' questions are, but my question is 'can it be done out of the box, or do I need to implement a specific thing for this?', so mainly my only option here was to post an explanation of all of the satchmo code I've been reading and say what I've understood so far.. I have (or had, at that point) no code at all to show for, and it actually wasn't done with 'code', but rather fiddling with settings, so.. 

My issue is fixed now, but it's just..

Comment: @Lacrymology: Any question that can be answered with a simple yes/no has a problem and probably isn't a "real question" as that is defined on StackOverflow.

Comment: I hear you.. voted to reopen the question if and when it's reopened feel free to post the solution and accept it so others can benefit from this. You might have evaded this facade by simply mentioning "I'm familiar with this and have experience" etc.. but what's done is done. :-/

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ oh, well.. whatever, it was NOT a yes/no question, a valid answer would've been: "yes, you can try with the tiered shipping module", or "no, you'll need to code, but you can make do with a hook and silently adding a shipping discount to your order".

Comment: @Lacrymology: Think of it this way... Any question that is closed can be reopened.  If the question has value, it can be edited to improve and to fix the issue.  You can then flag it for reopening.  I agree how we handle it right now isn't the best.  There are [proposals to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108535/temporarily-blocking-low-quality-question) [improve the process](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92939/i-think-stackoverflow-should-convert-to-catholicism-so-that-we-may-have-purgatory), but they aren't generally supported.  Perhaps you can think of a better way?