# Votes on review audit are not placed on the question

Tags: discussion, voting, review-audits

During a review on SO, I upvoted a question because it was of decent quality.
Turned out to be an audit.

The upvote halted the review, revealing it was an audit, got my pat on the head, etc.

However, the upvote I placed within the review (audit) area was not cast on the actual question the review (audit) was for.

This is possibly [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), for reasons known only to coders with 500mg caffeine per pint of blood by midday.
If it's not by design for any reason, can we have votes on review audits be cast on the actual question/answer?

If I vote on an answer or question during review, I want it to be cast, so same with an audit really. Also, if this occurs with downvotes, then it most certainly needs addressing, as downvotes are an important part of community moderating.

*[I put this question on MSE as could be relevant to other sites]*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, no - roughly half of audits are "known-bad" audits where the post is *deleted*, and allowing you to vote on a deleted post would break the normal rules - [even moderators can't do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242062/please-let-me-kick-a-bad-post-when-its-down).

Even for "known-good" posts, letting your upvotes count isn't ideal - we're not picking these randomly, and posts generally get re-used for audits... So the net effect would be to greatly increase the score of a handful of posts that were chosen because they *already* scored more than the norm.

That said, if you see a post in review that you really like, don't hesitate to click through to the normal question page and vote on it there.

Comment: ah fairynuff, that makes sense. Cheers.