# Stack Exchange appears to be less suitable for inexperienced coders than it used to be before

Tags: discussion, question-quality

In the past, the programming sites of Stack Exchange (e.g. Stack Overflow) used to accept fairly straightforward questions about HTML, CSS, JS and alike, scripting in powershell or BASH or simple problems in C#.

However, these days such questions appear to be downvoted and closed.

What happened to those communities an why aren't they accepting simple questions anymore?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit this question into something that fits better a constructive discussion. Feel free to rollback if that is not your intention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downvotes and close of beginner question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119059/downvotes-and-close-of-beginner-question) (same question asked 6 years before)

Comment: Similar discussion on Meta Stack Overflow: [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)

Comment: You know how annoying Donkey is during the trip to Far, Far Away, continually asking the same question: "Are we there yet?", over, and over, and over again?   That's how experienced SO users feel about the 'Computers 101' questions that are better answered  by a textbook, tutorial site, Google, prof, TA, teacher; anything  but yet another 'look it up for me' demand:(

Answer (score 9):

If you conisder yourself as a less experienced programmer or coder, chances very likely are, your questions have been asked many times and you don't need to ask one more. All you need to do is to search on Google for your problem.

If you insist that your problem is unique, ask yourself if you've really done enough research. "I Googled it for 10 minutes" is not a good indication of having spent effort. If you think "I don't want to know why, just tell me how to make my code work", then your question would still not be accepted on Stack Overflow (or a sister site).

If you've really spent effort on your problem and still can't figure out why, include them in your question and go ahead and ask. It's likely that your question will be upvoted and answered. That says, not all "simple problems" are rejected, provided they're in-line with existing requirements for being asked as a question.

Comment: Even "I Googled it for 10 minutes" would be a start, but more importantly, users should tell the community what was the query used in their search.

Comment: Related: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4642212).